# HasChild and function score sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

in our project we are using hasChild sorting which is exactly by the book:

> {
>       "query": {
>           "has_child" : {
>               "type" : "blog_tag",
>               "score_mode" : "max",
>               "query" : {
>                   "function_score" : {
>                       "script_score": {
>                           "script": "_score * doc['click_count'].value"
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>       }
>    }

The problem is that when I have "score_mode" it returns the following error:

> "reason":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"failed to run inline
>   script ["_score * doc['clickcount'].value] using lang
>   [groovy]","caused_by":{"type":"missing_property_exception","reason":"No
>   such property:

Getting rid of the "score_mode" will show results that are not sorted. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

**EDIT:**
Here is the full error. The above example is from the documentation as my info is confidential and I had to replace with example. In the following error I have also replaced some names.

> {"took":24,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":2,"failed":2,"failures":[{"shard":1,"index":"my_index","node":"qA2MHVABTHKXs6Le0TD0iQ","reason":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"failed
>   to run inline script [_score * doc['type.clickcount'].value] using
>   lang
>   [groovy]","caused_by":{"type":"missing_property_exception","reason":"No
>   such property: type for class:
>   c47126be960099501d9aebe33d6f1e7666fdff5e"}}}]},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}

Comment: Could you put all of the error in the question?

Comment: The query in your questiom has click_count. The error message has clickcount . Is that something you renamed before posting?

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Yes, it's renamed and version of the elasticsearch is 2.3.5

Comment: The error seems to be showing `_score * doc['type.clickcount'].value` but you have a different script in your query

Comment: Correct I replaced it. My script represents only the value of one field that is timestamp minus a digit: "doc['type.timestamp'].value - 12345678"

Comment: @Yovo. I am facing the same problem... Did you got any solution for this problem. For me the error is like: No such property: _score for class:

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, you have `score` instead of `_score`

```
score * doc['clickcount'].value
```

should read

```
_score * doc['clickcount'].value
^
|
```

Comment: sorry somehow I deleted the underscore in the error but it is there

Comment: Can you show a sample document and/or your mapping?

Comment: the data is confidential so I can't really show my mapping :(

Comment: The mapping doesn't contain any data :)